# How do I clear the search field with angular?

Tags: angularjs, search

I've added a clear button in my HTML but I'm still a newbie. How would I make my clear button empty the search field on click? If a user enters some text and nothing comes up, I'd like to be able to wipe it out.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kiddigit/znasgeez/1/

```
  <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">
    <span ng-model="search" ng-click="clearSearch()"></span> Clear
  </button>


var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
  });
}]);

artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

    if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
      $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1;
    } else {
      $scope.prevItem = $scope.artists.length-1;
    }

    if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.artists.length-1) {
      $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
    } else {
      $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }

  });
}]);
```

Comment: your sample doesn't work, and has a lot of issues that need corrected to make it functional (functions outside the controller definition, for example).  You should try to ensure that code illustrating your issue is usable before posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using angular.copy({}). Which will empty your fields.
Have a look at the plunker I created:https://plnkr.co/edit/LYZeKt3jZXhoCmfvgmLw?p=preview

```
$scope.search = angular.copy($scope.default);
```

is the key here.

Comment: Thanks! Took some messing around with my code but I got it. Still not "getting" Angularjs but getting closer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just set the scope variable that your input is bound to to an empty string.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5156/

basically, in your clearSearch() method you do

```js
$scope.query = "";
```